# Rewrite mysite.com/app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id to mysite.com/app/app-name/numeric-id/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, cpanel

I am new to PHP and server-side operations so asking this basic question here. I found a lot of similar questions and answers here but I fail to achieve what I want. How can I write my htaccess file to produce these results?

Dynamic URL:

```
mysite.com/app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id
```

URL I want:

```
mysite.com/app/example-name/numeric-id
```

Comment: Try this tool: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/?_ga=1.71498199.531713750.1430649105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /app.php?appname=$1&appid=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

EDIT :

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} app\.php\?appname=(.*?)&appid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /app/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^app/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?$ /app.php?appname=$1&appid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to include everything in the parameters... `[a-z0-9-]+` and `[\d+]` is better.

Comment: Drakes, can you please suggest a right title? I'm sorry if it misleads. I've mentioned that I'm new to PHP concepts, BTW Starkeen answered what I asked :)

Comment: @Starkeen: Can you please help me redirecting the first case to second one as a 301 redirect? The code is working and I can access the page at friendly URL now, but it is accessible at the other one too. (At ?appname=app_name&appid=appid). I want it to be 301 redirected to /app/app_name_/appid

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the updated answer, I have reupdated it.

Answer (score 2):

To rewrite

> http://mysite.com/app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id

to

> http://mysite.com/app/example-name/numeric-id

you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} appname=([^?&]+)&appid=([^?&]+) [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} appid=([^?&]+)&appname=([^?&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^app\.php.*$ /app/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

These rules capture the query string parameters you want, then use them in the rewrite in the order they were captured. There are two conditions in case the order of the parameters are switched. The trailing question mark (`?`) removes the original query string from the rewritten output.

**301 Redirect Tip:**

If your past *.htaccess* rules contain a 301 redirects (301 = permanent), even if it is incorrect, your browser will cache that redirect and not consult the *.htaccess* anymore for that URL.

For testing, use 302 redirects, then when you are satisfied switch to 301. If it's too late, then try adding another parameter to your request to temporarily bypass this, like:

> app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id **&nonce=1234**

or, clear your browser cache, or use an *ingocnito* window.

Comment: i've tested, it lose appname value

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this but the "appname" isn't generated in URL. Still a 404 error is generated. The first solution is working as of now.

Comment: Can you please help a little more? how would I be able to redirect (301) requests from http://example.com/app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id to http://example.com/app/example-name/numeric-id? The URL rewriting is working fine now.

Comment: @Drakes, RewriteRule receives only  pattern from THE LAST matched RewriteCond, so your case of htaccess never makes appname

Comment: @Drakes, tester works, result does not achieved on real apache, my sentence is based on specification - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond :(  It would be succesfully, if you was right

Comment: @splash58 I went to prove you wrong in a real box, but it turns out you are right. My apologies. I'll fix it with something different. Again, my apologies.

Comment: @Drakes, I am glad that you have found the truth :)))

Comment: @rehmat The simulator failed me. Apologies. Please see my updated answer. It works on a live box as I just tested it on my own system. Please let me know if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: @Drakes, have you tested it on real apache? I don't understand why, but when i write RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=([^?&]+)&b=([^?&]+) [NC], it works. And when  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} appname=([^?&]+)&appid=([^?&]+) [NC] - does not. Whats wrong ? :(

Comment: Same issue here, still didn't work for me :( Don't know why. Drakes, if you have tested it, then I may be doing something wrong. BTW the answer by Starkeen is working.

Comment: @rehmat, answer of Starkeen must work. And the answer is not better. The problem is that the solution looks clear does not work :)

Comment: Yes, it is working. Sometimes logic fails and we need to dig deeper into the issues ;)

Comment: @rehmat The reason that your are both experiencing problems is because in your previous attempts to use past rules in .htaccess with 301 redirects, your browser permanently thinks that your `app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id` should go to whatever failed redirect you had before. Try adding another parameter to your request to verify this, e.g. `app.php?appname=example-name&appid=numeric-id&nonce=1234`. I've tried these rules on a real, live server.