# Rewrite URL from post name to URL friendly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have permalinks turned on with post name in Wordpress.

I'm wanting to rewrite my url from 
**`/property-details/?Prop_ID=10006958&Prop_Name=test`** to **`/property-details/10006958/test`**

Current `htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012589/rewrite-mysite-com-app-phpappname-example-nameappid-numeric-id-to-mysite-com-a/30012766

Comment: `/property-details/?Prop_ID=10006958&Prop_Name=test` is not using the postname. Have you got mod_rewrite in apache?