# .htaccess redirect to requested filename with pretty URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect to the requested file name so if someone types

```
www.example.com/user/1
```

it should redirect to the `user.php` file with 1 lets so someone type

`www.example.com/apple/3` or `www.example.com/apple` which does not exists but it should redirect still redirect to apple which will auto give `404`

I have no idea on how to do this i found this code here it works but redirects everything to index.php even if i type apple

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SimpleMVCTest/

#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

Edit:
Little more detail

can `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]` be dynamic so instead of index.php it gets the requested one from the url?

so if a user types `www.example.com/{requested URL?something=something}`

then i want `.htaccess` to redirect to `{requested URL/something/something}` and all to be dynamic to if a user types cars or pear or rabbit/3 it would redirect to that page without it being hard coded in `htaccess` like `rabbit.php?someting=someting` i want every thing to be dynamically so something like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ {requested URL?something=something}?get=$1 [L]`

## Edit 2:

OK after a lot Google/Youtube/Stackoverflow research and putting random things together I finally got something that partly works here:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /SimpleMVCTest/


#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to REQUESTED_FILENAME
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?get=$1 [L]
```

There is two issues I have noticed with this

1: Giving `www.example.com/car/1` will result in 500 Internal Error but if i write `www.example.com/car` it works fine. How do i make it so i can go car/1 and it will not give 500 internal Error

2: if i write `www.example.com/somethingthatdoesnotexist` or `www.example.com/somethingthatdoesnotexist/1` it gives 500 internal but should just redirect to 404 but it's not found

How would I do this?

Comment: What does "redirect to the user.php file with 1" mean here?

Comment: @Drakes Get User by Id one

Comment: Can you please show some input urls and the desired rewritten urls exactly as you want them? Give 2 or 3 examples because your question as written is not clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Drakes Added more detail hopefully it helps

Comment: You want `www.example.com/file.php?param=value` rewritten to `www.example.com/file/param/value` then? If this is not correct, then please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012589/rewrite-mysite-com-app-phpappname-example-nameappid-numeric-id-to-mysite-com-a/30012766#30012766) as an example how to show before and after urls.

Comment: @Drakes Hi, Look at edit 2 in the question i found something that partly works but needs to be fixed thanks!

Comment: I'm good with htaccess, but I've asked you 3 times now to clearly supply input urls and expected output urls, not `{requested URL?something=something`. You are trying to do something by "putting random things together" you don't fully understand. Instead, include what is asked of you and we can help. Give clear, exact examples of input urls, and expected output urls. No guesses. Just this.

Comment: @Drakes ok my bad, the url i want is like this:    `www.example.com/index.php` to redirect as 'www.example.com/index', i want `www.example.com/users.php`  to go to `www.example.com/users' also if something gets passed like `www.example.com/users.php?user=1` to `/user/1`

Comment: There is literally _hundreds of thousands_ of resources on the Internet for creating “pretty” URLs with .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

In a .htaccess file use the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user$ user.php
RewriteRule ^user/$ user.php
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ user.php?user=$1
```

If you use as a link now something like profile/username it will show that users profile.

It may mess up some css an js files, if it does on the page in the head use:

```
<base href="/" />
```

This should correct any css/js/image links

Comment: OK this works but can  `RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ user.php?user=$1` be done dynamically? so instead of hard coding user.php it gets the requested one from the url?

Comment: Do you mean like <a href="user/{username here}"></a> or similar?

Comment: found this but not sure if its correct `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and instead of index.php?user=$1 it should be requestedurl.php?user=$1 so it all happens dynamically? kind of get the idea?

Comment: Hi, Look at edit 2 in the question i found something that partly works but needs to be fixed thanks!